# @mui/system, Override theme type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How do I make `@mui/system` aware of my theme settings?

When using `Stack`'s sx prop, theme is defined in [createTheme.d.ts](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/db6c358d0e83da10968ec81b1a95e11a8e3bb3d0/packages/mui-system/src/createTheme/createTheme.d.ts#L33), but there doesn't seem to be a way to extend or provide overrides.

As a workaround, I'm using `styled` to extend `Stack` with my theme values.

Comment: I think `@mui/system` is not aware of custom themes, instead you could try importing from `@mui/material`.

Comment: @Camilo oh, ok, I thought the release notes said `Stack` was "moved" but it was actually just "added" to `@mui/system`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Camilo stated, use `import {Stack} from "@mui/material"` instead of from `@mui/system`.